# Loop through Pandas Dataframe with unique column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following question and I need help to apply the for loop to iterate through dataframe columns with unique values. For ex I have the following df.

```
col1  col2  col3
aaa   10    1
bbb   15    2
aaa   12    1
bbb   16    3
ccc   20    3
ccc   50    1
ddd   18    2
```

I had to apply some manipulation to the dataset for each unique value of col3. Therefore, what I did is I sliced out the df with col3=1 by:

```
df1 = df[df['col3']==1]
#added all processing here in df1#
```

Now I need to do the same slicing for col3==2 ... col3==10, and I will be applying the same manipulation as I did in col3==1. For ex I have to do:

```
df2 = df[df['col3']==2]
#add the same processing here in df2#
df3 = df[df['col3']==3]
#add the same processing here in df3#
```

Then I will need to append them into a list and then combine them at the end.
I couldn't figure out how to run a for loop that will go through col3 column and look at the unique values so I don't have to create manually ten dfs.
I tried to groupby then apply the manipulation but it didn't work.
I appreciate help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simple solution. just iterate on the unique values of this column and loc the rows with this unique value. like this:

```
dfs=[]
for i in df["col3"].unique():
    df_i = df.loc[df["Cluster"]==i,:]
    dfs.append(df_i.copy())
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it but will be slow for large dataframes.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

for _, v in df.iterrows():
    if v[2] == 1:
        # add your code
        df1 = df1.append(v)
    elif v[2] == 2:
        # add your code
        df2 = df2.append(v)
    elif v[2] == 3:
        # add your code
        df3 = df3.append(v)
```

You can then use `pd.concat()` to rebuild to one df.

Output of `df1`

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   aaa     10      1
2   aaa     12      1
5   ccc     50      1
```

Comment: Thanks Cam, I will give it a go. In any case, it seems there is no way to avoid writing the same code multiple times for each if condition? This 'code' is a bit lengthy, and I thought if there is any way to write it only once within a for loop.

Comment: You can put your code in a function and then just call it each time.

Comment: Does my solution solve your problem? If not let me know. If yes please accept answer.

Comment: Thanks Cam, in fact I had to write it manually as I originally showed. I tried to use your suggestion with df.iterrows, however it got the orders mixed up in the final df because inside a for loop it loops through randomly whatever v[2] comes first. In my case, I sorted v[2] values first and then added my processing. I think it is a bit hard to explain given the nature of the problem. Thanks anyways.